# How to update related messages in kafka topic if incoming message has reference to them only inside value?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need to merge the payload if the reference number(refNo) is the same in different messages. My limitation is that I can only use a `KTable` and if the key is an **even number** I don't need to merge the payload. Additionally, the order of incoming messages should not change the result.

For example, if we have an empty topic and incoming messages are:

```
1: { key: "1", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data1}} }
2: { key: "2", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data2}} }
3: { key: "3", value: {refNo:2, payload:{data3}} } // this one should be not effected and left how it is
```

Expected result:

```
1: { key: "1", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data1, data2}} }
2: { key: "2", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data2}} }
3: { key: "3", value: {refNo:2, payload:{data3}} }
```

The only way I can think of to do this is to use two times `.groupBy` and join with the original topic everything again.

1. First change the key to `refNo`, save the key to the value itself, and join the payload during aggregation.
2. Secondly `.groupBy` revert key to the initial state.
3. The last step joins everything to the original topic because I lost one message during grouping by.

I'm pretty sure there's an easier way to do this. What is the most optimized and elegant way to solve this issue?

Edit: Its downstream and there is output topic, original is not edited.

Comment: Hello @Vytautas, are you sure that in your output you should see this message:  

2: { key: "2", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data2}} }  ?

Comment: why not just : 1: { key: "1", value: {refNo:1, payload:{data1, data2}} }
3: { key: "3", value: {refNo:2, payload:{data3}} }

Comment: I don't want message with key "2" just to disappear. I'm using output topic as global table later and its exposed trough an API. If someone would need that data, it would not be available anymore.

Comment: would not it be simpler to use another topic for the merged payloads? only downside seems to be data duplication

Comment: Combine the messages downstream. Dump messages into Elasticsearch or similar, then combine as necessary and shoot them off into another topic or the final consumer. You don't even need massive retention for your Elastic cluster, just enough to fit the maximum time window plus a little wiggle room.

Comment: Alternatively, consume using Logstash (since working with Kafka is exceptionally easy), make your transforms, then just shoot them back into Kafka.

Comment: Sounds kind of work around, not actual apache kafka-streams solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I'm going with this solution. It works, but I have no idea how it will perform, or can it be more optimized, or if there is better way to solve my issue.

```
KStream<String, Value> even = inputTopicStream.filter((key, value) -> value.isEven()));

inputTopicStream.toTable(Materialized.with(String.serdes, Value.serde))
   .groupBy(
      (key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(new Key(value.getRefNo(), addKeyToValue(key, value)),
      Grouped.with("aggregation-internal", String.serdes, Value.serde))
   .aggregate(
      Value::new,
      (key, value, agg) -> mergePayload(key, value, agg), // ensure that key is uneven after merge
      (key, value, agg) -> handleSplit(key, value, agg))
   .toStream()
      .selectKey((key, value) -> new Key(value.getKey())) // restore original key
      .merge(even) // need to merge even key stream, because they was lost during aggregation
      .to(OUTPUT_TOPIC, Produced.with(String.serde, Value.serde));
```

Answer (score 0):

Aggregating within KSQL could probably accomplish exactly this. You can use any of the aggregate functions like `COLLECT_LIST(col1) => ARRAY`

The only issue is how large of a window you would need. How frequently do you need to concatenate the data?

Also, it feels like a big "no" to write back to the original topic.

1. You're changing the message format slightly, additional downstream consumers could have been expecting a specific message format.
2. Writing to a new topic seems like a better route to go, it also decreases the amount of messages additional consumers need to consume.

Comment: I'm using tables, so there is no windows, any incoming new message should update another message which have related refNo. Maybe my question is bad, but I had no intention to change original topic. Yes new topic is result of all the changes.